# Minikube automatically runs images from docker registry

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am trying to learn Kubernetes and installed Minikube on my local. I created a sample python app and its corresponding image was pushed to public docker registry. I started the cluster with

```
kubectl apply -f <<my-app.yml>>
```

It got started as expected. I stopped Minikube and deleted all the containers and images and restarted my Mac.

> My Questions

I start my docker desktop and as soon as I run

```
minikube start
```

Minikube goes and pulls the images from public docker registry and starts the container. Is there a configuration file that Minikube looks into to start my container that I had deleted from my local? I am not able to understand from where is Minikube picking up my-app's configurations which was defined in manifest folder.

I have tried to look for config files and did find cache folder. But it does not contain any information about my app

Answer (score 1):

I found this is expected behavior:

> *minikube stop* command should stop the underlying VM or container, but keep user data intact.

So when I manually delete already created resources it does not automatically starts.

More information :
https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/13552